# AVAudioSession does not automatically connect to Bluetooth A2DP audio?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession, ios-bluetooth

Description:

When I change my `AudioSession` to `.playAndRecord` via the following call:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .mixWithOthers])
```

From these category options set, I expect that, once I pair bluetooth headphones with my phone, my running app should automatically route audio to my bluetooth A2DP headphones. Instead, my app still chooses to use the phone speaker. There is no indication at all, whether from querying the audio session instance or in the form of a route change notification, that I have bluetooth headphones connected..

**Question: How do I ensure the audiosession connects automatically to the bluetooth headphones?**

This behavior clearly has nothing to do with an incorrect line of code. As if I had bluetooth headphones paired before the I invoke audio-session category change, my audio will correctly continue to use the bluetooth headphones.

Moreover, if I had instead used the `.allowBluetooth` category option (for HFP instead of A2DP) during the code invocation, and then paired bluetooth headphones, the headphones connect automatically just fine. Behavior reproduced on: iPhone XR (iOS 13.6.1) with Apple AirPods Pro
iPhone XR (iOS 13.6) with Senso wireless 44.1kHz bluetooth headphones.

Reproduction steps:

For the sake of simplicity and reproducibility for Apple’s engineers, I have reproduced the issue on a lightly modified version of [AVEchoTouch Demo Code from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/audio_playback_recording_and_processing/avaudioengine/using_voice_processing?language=objc). As this was a demo project published by Apple, it is all correct code. My modified project, called `BluetoothIssue`, can be found [here](https://github.com/winstondu/BluetoothIssueA2DP).

Step 1: Make sure your bluetooth headphones are currently not paired with the iPhone.

Step 2: Launch the “BluetoothIssue App”. When you toggle the “FX Out” or the “Speech Out” toggles, the app should be playing sounds (out of iPhone speaker)

Step 3: Now connect your bluetooth headphones to the phone. Even though the headphones are now connected and paired with phone, the app does not register the connection, and continues play out of the phones built-in speakers.

// Steps 4-5 (Optional): to see that nothing is wrong with the app’s category itself

Step 4: Now force kill the “BluetoothIssue” app, while your headphones are still connected.

Step 5: Now relaunch the “BluetoothIssue” app. The app plays sound correctly out to the bluetooth headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that if i set the mode to VideoRecording, iOS will change the route if I turn the bluetooth on (and I get a route change notification). Without this mode I had to allow both bluetooth, after detect one, change the category again without AllowBluetooth, just A2DP. Weird and slow solution, but worked. Now im just using videorecording mode.

Comment: so you managed to use both the phone mic with A2DP BT headphones with "videorecording" mode?

Comment: The builtin microphone and BT A2DP headphone worked always if you started the app with them already connected.  But the only way to get a AudioSession notification if the BT heaphone is connected AFTER the app is open is by setting the session to videoRecording mode.
Its important to note that with this mode some iPhones can change the data source of the builtin microphone to another microphone (e.g. "Bottom" changes to "Front" microphone). Of course you can revert that change manually if this is necessary for you.

Comment: @RogerioBelsa, thank you. It's really annoying that Apple labeled this as not a bug!

Comment: Yeah! There is another minor "issue" with this "fix": Depending upon the model of the Phone, it can change the source of the built-in microphone when in VideoRecording Mode (in my case, changed from "Top" to "Bottom") You can change the source back if you want, but usually this is not a big deal.